# How to read my xml in a link using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml

I have my xml in a link and I would like to parse ampscript, how could I read the XML in my ampscript?
XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cart>
      <items>
            <item>
                  <sku><![CDATA[123]]></sku>
                  <name><![CDATA[Square]]></name>
                  <url><![CDATA[https://example.com?sku=123]]></url>
            </item>
            <item>
                  <sku><![CDATA[456]]></sku>
                  <name><![CDATA[Circle]]></name>
                  <url><![CDATA[https://example.com?sku=456]]></url>
            </item>
            <item>
                  <sku><![CDATA[789]]></sku>
                  <name><![CDATA[Triangle]]></name>
                  <url><![CDATA[https://example.com?sku=789]]></url>
            </item>
      </items>
</cart>
```

What did i try :

```
%%[
  

var @xml, @nodes, @rowCount
set @xml = HTTPGet('http://www.example.com')

if indexOf(@xml,"<cart>") > 0 then

  set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/cart/items/item",0)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

  if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      var @nodepath
      var @sku
      var @name
      var @url

      set @nodepath = concat("/cart/items/item[",@i,"]/")

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"sku"))) > 0 then
          set @sku = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"sku"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"name"))) > 0 then
          set @name = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"name"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"url"))) > 0 then
          set @url = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"url"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if not empty(@sku) and not empty(@name) and not empty(@url) then

      ]%%

       <br><a href="%%=redirectto(@url)=%%">%%=v(@sku)=%%</a> - <a href="%%=redirectto(@url)=%%">%%=v(@name)=%%</a>

      %%[

      endif

    next @i

  else

   outputline(concat("<br>no products found"))

  endif

else

  outputline(concat("<br>no XML found"))

endif

]%%
```

And the result is - no products found

I would like to read the xml by the link in the ampscript and the output be the content from the link but already parsed

Comment: What do you mean by "reference the xml by its link"?  Please update your question to include the desired output.

Comment: Hi, Adam I have updated the question adding more about what I want to do, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not following.  What do you want to do with the link?  In the example the XML URL can be dynamic if you want -- the `@xml` can reference whatever returns XML. The `url` field is the _link_ from the XML.

Comment: There are also [plenty of examples](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a5202%20%5bmarketing-cloud%5d%20buildrowsetfromxml) of parsing XML around here.

Comment: In a nutshell I want to read the xml link in my ampscript to then execute the rest of my code,   I will look in others questions as well, thanks!!